# Is it possible to get the xpath (source) of an element using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, xml.etree

If you take a look at this [site](https://example.com/), you will see the title/text "Example Domain". Is it possible to get its xpath which is `/html/body/div/h1` using selenium? Is there any other possibilities? I mean I want to get xpath itself and not its content!
I know we can get the page_soruce using `driver.page_source` but this not what I'm looking for. I simply expect an output as `/html/body/div/h1`.

I tried this:

```
test = driver.page_source
ps = str(test)
root = etree.fromstring(ps)
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)

find_text = etree.XPath("//p[text()='my_target_text']") # in our case Example Domain

for target in find_text(root):
    print(tree.getpath(target))
```

It returns:

> lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch

Answer (score 0):

What you need (based on how you worded your question: I honestly doubt this is what you **really** need, and I'm sure that if you would state your end goal, someone would put you on the right path) is this:

https://gist.github.com/ergoithz/6cf043e3fdedd1b94fcf

I figured this would actually represent a full answer to your question as asked, so posting it as a response.

Comment: I will look for it and accept your answer, if it is what I'm looking for. Anyway thx for your time.

Comment: This is useful and goes in the direction of what I'm looking for. But I'm looking for smth easier and shorter the make me achieve the same goal to integrate to my project. Because my project is complicated enough. I would not need more complications :-) But big thank!